# how to avoid preloading in Ecto Query Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a table `GateReportSubclass` (embeddings) and `GateReportEvent` (deliveries). A `GateReportSubclass` can have multiple `GateReportEvent`s such as

```
  schema "deliveries" do
    field(:cameraex, :string)
    field(:arrived_at, :utc_datetime)
    field(:left_at, :utc_datetime)

    belongs_to(:embedding_in, GateReportSubclass, foreign_key: :embedding_id_in)
    belongs_to(:embedding_out, GateReportSubclass, foreign_key: :embedding_id_out)
  end
```

and in `GateReportSubclass`

```
  schema "embeddings" do
    field(:cameraex, :string)
    field(:embeddings, :map)

    has_many(:in_deliveries, GateReportEvent, foreign_key: :embedding_id_in)
    has_many(:out_deliveries, GateReportEvent, foreign_key: :embedding_id_out)
  end
```

so, in `deliveries` there can be `embeddings`'s id in embedding_id_in/embedding_id_out.

I am trying to query `deliveries` with `arrived_at` or `left_at` to get a subclass that occurred on a specific date's event.

I have this query

```
GateReportSubclass
|> join(:left, [s], d in GateReportEvent,
  on: d.embedding_id_in == s.id or d.embedding_id_out == s.id
)
|> where([s], s.cameraex == ^exid)
|> where(
  query,
  [s, d],
  date_compare(^period, ^timezone, d.arrived_at, ^date) or
    date_compare(^period, ^timezone, d.left_at, ^date)
)
|> preload([:in_deliveries, :out_deliveries])
|> distinct([s], s.id)
|> select([:id, :class, :subclass, :cameraex, :features])
```

now this query works all fine. **BUT**

A `GateReportSubclass` can occur in more than 10K `GateReportEvent`s such as

- GateReportSubclass

  - in_deliveries [10k GateReportEvent]
  - out_deliveries [15k GateReportEvent]

In such cases query is very slow. and I want to get the sum of `in_deliveries` and `out_deliveries` as well. for that, I am doing this

```
subclasses =
  data.items
  |> Enum.reduce([], fn subclass, acc ->
    %{in_deliveries: in_deliveries, out_deliveries: out_deliveries} = subclass
    occurances = Enum.count(in_deliveries) + Enum.count(out_deliveries)
    elem = subclass |> Map.from_struct() |> Map.put(:occurances, occurances)
    [acc | [elem]]
  end)
  |> List.flatten()
```

I want to avoid this `preload` but also want to count the number of the total in and out events as well. Can you guide me in this, I hope I explained it well. Thanks in advance

```
Map.put(data, :items, subclasses)
```

Comment: you can pass a query for preload: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-queries

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the GateReportEvents preloaded, then remove the `|> preload([:in_deliveries, :out_deliveries])` from your query.  You can use aggregate functions in the select statement, which will perform the aggregation functions on the database server, and not in your application code.  This will be MUCH faster and more efficient.

You might want to try something like this:

```
from(
   grs in GateReportSubclass,

   left_join: gre in GateReportEvent,
   on: gre.embedding_id_in == grs.id or gre.embedding_id_out == grs.id,

   where: grs.cameraex == ^exid
   where: # put your date filtering clause here,

   select: %{
     id: grs.id,
     in_count: filter(sum(1), not is_nil(gre.embedding_id_in)),
     out_count: filter(sum(1), not is_nil(gre.embedding_id_out))
  }
) |> Repo.one()
```

This may need some tweaking as I cant test it, but seems like it should work.

Comment: Note the filter synatx will only work on postgres, otherwise you'll have to use a fragment with a case statement.